# Aspect not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop

I am working on a simple project, where I want to use aspects. I have created a jar which has my aspects (code is below)

```
package com.example.aop.logging.aspect;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(com.example.aop.logging.aspect.Loggable)")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.print("***********Before************" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " called with param -> "
                + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    }
}
```

Below is my Loggable annotation

```
package com.example.aop.logging.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {

}
```

I want to include this jar in another spring boot project, which has my apis

```
package com.example.server.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.example.aop.logging.aspect.Loggable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CreateController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CreateController.class);
    
    @Loggable
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    @PostMapping("/create/{userId}")
    public Topic create(@PathVariable String userId) {
        
        LOGGER.debug("Inside createTopic -3 :::" );     
    }   
}
```

The aspect is not getting invoked, can you please help

Comment: my advice, don't do it like that, create custom annotations to mark your joinpoints. unless you want to add config for each and every joinpoint you create

Comment: also: how do you link your 'MyAspect' to the library with the controller?

Comment: do you have @EnableAspectJAutoProxy on a configuration?

Comment: I have added the jar (containing MyAspect) as a dependency to my api. Secondly, can you please help me with an example for what you are proposing

Comment: @zlaval I added `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to  MyAspect class, still no success

Comment: put it on a class annotated with `@Configuration`, not the component itself

Comment: @Stultuske as per your suggestion, I have created a new custom annotation, still no success

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala confirm if the package `com.example.aop.logging.aspect` falls in the ComponentScan of your project . Could you please share the package of the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks R.G. the problem was ComponentScan